# use offset and limit in mongodb select

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Here is the code that I am using in meanstack to get the limited data

```
apiRouter.get('/pagination_posts', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params)       // getting object having value for limit and offset
    Post.count({},function(err,count){
        console.log(count)     // total number of records
        Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json({total:count,posts:posts});
        }).skip(req.query.offset).limit(req.query.limit);
    });
});
```

Getting following error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
    at /Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/server/api/posts.js:29:9
    at /Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3822:16
    at /Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/node_modules/kareem/index.js:213:48
    at /Volumes/E/simerjit/fwrkdeploy/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

If I am using static values here `}).skip(0).limit(10);`, it is working fine, but I want to use this api for pagination, so need to pass dynamic limit and offset.

Comment: `if (err) res.send(err);` It's not like invoking a callback or promise resolve/reject where it branches out. It actually allows the next line of code to execute. So instead either use `else` or `return` i.e `if (err) return res.send(err);` to stop further execution. Then of course you need to fix your other error. Note that you are not checking the error status on `.count()`. You really should. You really should be using promises and chaining, or better yet `async/await` and a `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you have to stop your async code using return keyword or handle the proper condition flow will slove you issue  {I am using return below}

```
  apiRouter.get('/pagination_posts', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.params)       // getting object having value for limit and offset
        Post.count({},function(err,count){
            console.log(count)     // total number of records
            Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
                if (err) return res.json(err);  
               return res.json({total:count,posts:posts});
            }).skip(req.query.offset).limit(req.query.limit);
        });
    });
```

> other wise maintain the Condition controll flow

```
apiRouter.get('/pagination_posts', function(req, res){
            console.log(req.params)       // getting object having value for limit and offset
            Post.count({},function(err,count){
                console.log(count)     // total number of records
                Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
        if (err) ? res.json(err):  res.json({total:count,posts:posts});
                }).skip(req.query.offset).limit(req.query.limit);
            });
        });
```